# change setTimeout function to make the for loop print in ascending order

Tags: javascript, settimeout

```js
function randomNum(){
    let data;
    for(let i=1;i<=10;i++){       
        let time = Math.random()*100;
        setTimeout(()=>console.log(i,time),time)
    }
}
randomNum();
```

> For Each iteration, the program needs to stop for random **`time`**, then **`i`** should be printed and the loop continued

Comment: random vs ascending? please add what you want.

Comment: do you want to print a random number from the loop in ascending order?

Comment: It seem like a exam, can we use `async/await` syntax?

Comment: yes, only using async and await

Answer (score 0):

```js
function randomNum() {
  let timeToWait = 0; // here
  for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    let time = Math.random() * 100;
    timeToWait += time; // here
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(i, time);
    }, timeToWait); // update here. Updated
  }
}
randomNum();

async function randomNum2() {
  for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    let time = Math.random() * 100;
    await new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(i, time);
        resolve();
      }, time);
    })
  }
}

randomNum2();
```

You have to calculate time to wait for the next time.

In this case, in "next" time of the loop, time need to wait is total time to wait of before times.

Update the way using `async/await`.

Comment: thank you. But  Can we solve that with async and await

Comment: @HamsaVardhanDarapureddi Updated.